# Implicit error with matplotlib2tikz thisrow already exists

Tags: pgfplots, errors, matplotlib2tikz

The conversion from Python 3.7 into LaTeX code worked well with matplotlib2tikz v0.6.18.
The only exceptions are some ignored parameters which seems reasonably discarded for me (aspect ratio and tick label text width).
I am using the current version of pgfplots which is 1.16.

When compiling with either pdflatex or lualatex, it fails with the following puzzling error message - puzzling as there is no explicit `thisrow` argument:

```
! Package PGF Math Error:
The function `thisrow' already exists.
```

---

The simplified the code and tracked the error down to the begin of the axis environment or the first path command inside. Here the buggy MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1}]
\nextgroupplot[]
\path [fill=green] (axis cs:.1,.1) --(axis cs:.1,.12)
--(axis cs:.12,.12) --(axis cs:.12,.1) --(axis cs:.1,.1)
--cycle;

\begin{axis}
\path [fill=red] (axis cs:.1,.1) --(axis cs:.1,.12)
--(axis cs:.12,.12) --(axis cs:.12,.1) --(axis cs:.1,.1)
--cycle;
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}
\path [draw=white, fill=white] (axis cs:0,0) --(axis cs:0,1)
--(axis cs:1,1) --(axis cs:1,0) --cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you adding axis environments inside a groupplot? Shouldn't you do `\nextgroupplot[]` instead?

Comment: It seems not the only or entire problem... I replaced it as you said and further problems appeared. It seems that the converter `matplotlib2tikz` is incompatible with the Python3.7 command `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor()`...

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any reference to either `matplotlib2tikz` or `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor()` in your MWE. All you have is some axis environments with paths inside them in a `groupplot` setting. How about you update your MWE to get rid of the axis environments and to illustrate the problems mentioned in your comment?

Comment: Well I did not mention it in the MWE but the first line of the question. After some trials and searching on github, I found out that the 3d export function is not supported. Therefore I suggest either you write an answer and I accept it or I delete this question.

Comment: In its present form, I am not sure if the question will be helpful for many. There are two issues: the first one on `axis` vs. `\nextgroupplot`, which most likely has an answer somewhere, and the second one being the `matplot` issue, which I can't say much on. I guess that, if you want to help the community, you may want to split your question in two such that a google search will lead to something with the relevant information in.

Comment: I did not find any axis vs nextgroupplot answer but feel free to reduce it to such otherwise I delete it. The `matplotlib2tikz` part seems a bug - I reported on [Github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12373)

Comment: OK, I try to write something useful. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that you should use `\nextgroupplot` instead of an axis environment inside a group plot. Notice also that the paths you draw will get clipped away as pgfplots computes the bounding boxes on the basis of the plots, not on the basis of Ti*k*Z paths. However, it is easy enough to convert your paths to plots. And finally, as you seem to aim at 3 plots, you may want to use `group size=3 by 1`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 1}]
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(.1,.1) (.1,.12)
(.12,.12) (.12,.1) (.1,.1)};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot [fill=red] coordinates {(.1,.1) (.1,.12)
(.12,.12) (.12,.1) (.1,.1)};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot [draw=white, fill=white] coordinates {(0,0) (0,1)
(1,1) (1,0) };
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]